# Dynamically Set JTable Row Height

Tags: java, jtable

I am using a JTable to display multi-line data. My data is formatted using HTML and involves several lines for each cell. I want that whenever the table is resized the the JTable row heights to change dynamically to be able to display all the content.
So far, I have used this to dynamically resize the row heights inside my custom renderer class:

```
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
                int row, int column) {
            Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
           setSize(table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column).getWidth(), (int) getPreferredSize().getHeight());
            int height = getHeight();
            if (table.getRowHeight(row) != height){
                table.setRowHeight(row, height);
                table.repaint();
            }
            return c;
        }
```

The problem is that the height of the rows is being determined by the number of line breaks (`<br />`) in the cell content; i.e if the line has two line `<br />` tags, the row height will only adjust to an equivalent of two line heights. This ignores situations where some lines are long and wrap meaning the cell content will be more than two lines.
This is what I mean. My cell value looks something like:

```
String str = "<html> "
+ "<p style = \"font-family: 'Euphemia'; font-size: 1.1em;\"> "
+ "This is a line <br /> "
+ "This is a second line which will be very long causing it to automatically wrap to a new line <br /> "
+ "This is the third line. "
+ "</p> "
+ "</html> ";
```

In this case, since there are three `<br />` tags the row will be resized to an only show three lines hence hiding the last line.
I do prefer using html as it gives me the variety of formatting that I want to display the content. 
How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this to calculate size:

```
public Dimension calcSize(final String text)
{
  final JLabel l = new JLabel(text);
  return l.getPreferredSize();
}
```

You could move the `JLabel` out to a static field for speed optimization...